# 404 template for two different platforms within single project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, error-handling

I'm working with two different platforms within a single project: a Front-office (website) and the Back-office (admin-panel), and two different types of `404 page not found templates` are made: one for a simple visitor `/WEB-INF/JSP/front/ex-404.jsp` and one for a super-user (admin-panel) `/WEB-INF/JSP/admin/ex-404.jsp`.

Is it possible to show or compile the corresponding `ex-404.jsp` when this error occurs? Maybe by first triggering a certain servlet which defines the type of user and redirects to the right page? Or could a listener or a filter be used for this kind-of issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>be.mydomain.admin.servlets.MasterProductNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/JSP/admin/ex-productnotfound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>be.vdab.admin.servlets.MasterCategoryNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/JSP/admin/ex-categorynotfound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/JSP/admin/ex-404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/JSP/admin/ex-500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```